# How do I turn this data into a time series in R?

Tags: r, formatting, time-series, data-cleaning, holtwinters

I am having some issues getting this data to be a time series for a holt-winter model. I don't know what to do next.

```
library(reshape)
library(tidyr)

tempdata = as.matrix(read.table("https://d37djvu3ytnwxt.cloudfront.net/assets/courseware/v1/592f3be3e90d2bdfe6a69f62374a1250/asset-v1:GTx+ISYE6501x+2T2017+type@asset+block/temps.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))

#melt data for time series

tempdata.ts <- melt(tempdata, id=1:1)

#concatenate Date and Year

tempdata.ts <- tempdata.ts %>% unite(col = "Date", c(X1, X2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to fit `HoltWinters` from `stats`. This function requires `ts` object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
```

First, reshape data:

```
file <- "https://d37djvu3ytnwxt.cloudfront.net/assets/courseware/v1/592f3be3e90d2bdfe6a69f62374a1250/asset-v1:GTx+ISYE6501x+2T2017+type@asset+block/temps.txt"

read.table(file, header = TRUE, row.names = 1) %>% 
 as.data.frame() %>%
 mutate(DayMonth = rownames(.)) %>%
 gather(Date, Value, -DayMonth) %>%
 unite("Date", c(DayMonth, Date) ) %>% 
 mutate(Date = dmy(Date) ) -> tempData
```

Create time-series object:

```
tsData <- as.ts(
 tempData$Value, start = min(tempData$Date), end = max(tempData$Date),
 frequency = 365)
```